# MATLAB finding average RGB value across all pixels in image

Tags: image, matlab, colors, rgb, pixel

Code is below. I'm looping through an input image 1 pixel at a time and determining its RGB value. Afterwards i'm trying to find the average RGB value for the image overall. For some reason the averaging portion of my code isnt working though.

```
im = imread(filename);
[width, height, depth] = size(im);
count = 0;
r=0;
g=0;
b=0;
for x = 1 : width
    for y = 1: height
        r = r + im(x,y,1);
        g = g + im(x,y,2);
        b = b + im(x,y,3);     
        count = count + 1;
    end
end

%find averages of each RGB value.
r2 = r/count;
g2 = g/count;
b2 = b/count;
```

Comment: what are the data types of `r`, `g` and `b`? is it possible you are using `uint8` type variables to accumulate the intensities?

Answer (score 2):

Why not vectorizing and using `mean`?

```
mean( reshape( im, [], 3 ), 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code would work as well;

```
pep = imread('peppers.png');
mean(mean(pep))
```

This will return a 1x1x3 vector which will be the mean values of R, G, and B respectively.